# Create local files from a Django web

Tags: python, django

I have written a Django web run under Linux server, the web is used to read a

file path and generate some folders and files on the local machine which browse

the web, not sure how to do that, currently it can only generate the files on

the server runs the web locally.

Does it need to use the python package paramiko？

Thanks,
Le

Answer (score 1):

Django runs on server and every web server has no access to local (user) computer - it can't create folder on local computer (and it can't steal your files). It can only generate file and user can download it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,  how to generate file for user to download? Could you pls give the steps?

Comment: I would sad you already to it - when you click link (to open new page) then browser download html file but it doesn't ask where to save it but displays it. When server sends file then it adds HTTP header `content-type: some_file_type` and browser decidse what to do with this file. If you set `Content-Type: application/octet-stream` (and etc.) then browser will ask user where to save it. See more in Django doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/outputting-csv/